# Updating an existing Contact

Tags: xero-api

I am using xero-java-sdk.   I am looking at updating an existing contact.  There is a method in accountingApi

```
updateContact(contactId, contacts)
```

It is not clear on how to use that method.  Can someone give an example on how to use.